# Hashchange jQuery plugin - obtaining the current hash when clicking an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I'm using hashchange jQuery plugin from http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ to hook up an event when the window's location.hash changes.

I'd like to trigger a function when the hash changes that passes the new hash value (obtained with `event.fragment`) and the current hash value (the value just before the event is fired).

Here's a snipped of what I'd like to achieve:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(event){
   myFunction(event.fragment, /* currentHash */);
});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a property on location:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(event){
   myFunction(event.fragment, location.hash);
});
```

Or, store it yourself:

```
var lastHash = location.hash;                 //set it initially
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(event){
   myFunction(event.fragment, hashLash);      //previous hash
   lastHash = location.hash;                  //update it
});
```